# Почему появляется ошибка 504, при попытке попасть на страницу товара?

Tags: php, .htaccess, fail2ban

подскажите пожалуйста, это нормально, что у нас fail2ban такой полный? Подозреваю, что почти всех банит. У нас максимум 1.5к посетителей в день. Я начал обращать внимание, что когда кликаю сайт, использую поиск, потом резко перехожу на несколько товаров и так далее, у меня появляется ошибка 504.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, помочь в этом больше некому..

Также прикрепил видео проблемы [Видео](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/W5wSLmSQgIHyoA)

Сайты в видео:

[Сайт 1](https://steamninja.ru/)

[Сайт 2](https://steammix.ru/)

[Сайт 3](https://igro-zakup.ru/)

Можем ошибаться, но возможно проблема в этом, раньше такого не наблюдалось.. Это возникает при запросе к таблице в БД в которой хранится более 2к товаров. Всего сайтов 3 => 6к товаров
Со стороны мощности ВДС точно проблем нету.
Проблема проходит и впускает на сайт, если я зайду в инкогнито, но после нескольких попыток она опять появляется и через некоторое время сайт опять работает и по новой, такое чувство, что блочится IP.

[image: IMG]

Возможно проблема вовсе не в fail2ban, а в запросах. Которые на скриншоте, просто начали появляться. Если посмотрите на видео после такой долгой загрузки в итоге выбивает 504 и это на всех трех сайтах

Так выглядит .htaccess от домена [Игро-закуп](https://igro-zakup.ru/) , правильно ли он настроен?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^game/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /game.php?id_cat=$1&game=$2 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^seller/([^/]*)$ /seller.php?seller=$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^seller/([^/]*)/sort/([^/]*)$ /seller.php?seller=$1&sort=$2 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^goods/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /goods.php?goods=$1&game=$2 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: у вас там про редиректы написано. вы разобрались что с ними, или гадаете в чем проблема?

Comment: Нет, не разобрались

Answer (score 0):

1. Ошибка "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects" означает что для некоторых URL (или деректорий) действуют правила (RewriteRule и т.д.) переписывающие URL запроса более десяти раз (типа рекурсии - конфликтующие правила, например отправляющие A/B -> C/D -> A/B, или просто действительно 10 rewrite подряд).
   Если оно действительно нужно и оправдано (что странно), то увеличте лимит. Если нет, то поправте правила или добавте условия (RewriteCond и т.д.), чтобы запросы редиректило правильно.

   **UPD.** например я не уверен, что `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` действует всегда (нет якорей, этого файла может не быть, возможно надо было "!-f"), и если всё же нет, то правило `^(.*)$ $1.php` сделает из любого `файл.php` снова php, только уже `файл.php.php`, и повторив 10 раз то будет что-то типа `файл.php.php.....php.php.php` и оно на этом не остановится.
   Я не юзаю апач, но в nginx я бы написал без всякого условия (не уверен регулярки апача умеют negative lookahead), просто вместо `^(.*)$` например `^(.*)(?!\.php)$`.
   Хотя почему в RewriteCond только `.php`, а если там `.jpg` или что-то другое в том location?
2. Если в fail2ban есть какое-то правило действующее для 504 ответа, то это не совсем правильно если легальные запросы падают с "504 Gateway Timeout" (хотя тоже странно, почему не "505 Internal Server Error")...
   В этом случае лучше исключить либо URL-префикс сайтов (либо легальный referrer, cookie, или что-другое за что можно зацепится), или исключить 504, например если оно `[54]0\d`, то заменить на `(?:40\d|50(?!4)\d)`.

   Хотя то такое - правильней будет естественно поправить собственно ошибку, приводящую к бесконечным redirect... 
   И как минимум проверить фильтры и failregex на false positive при нормальной работе сайта.
   Например:

```bsh
# выбрать все запросы (ошибки) с моего IP из лога:
grep -wF 192.0.2.1 /var/log/some-error-log.log > /tmp/log
# показать сколько и какие regex сработают на той выдержке из лога:
fail2ban-regex /tmp/log "$failregex_or_filter"
```

Кроме того fail2ban не панацея и его нужно правильно настраивать/использовать, а выстрелить им (или другим каким IDS) в ногу проще простого, особенно если блочить <s>бездумно</s> превентивно все ошибки подряд - см. например [habr :: Блокировка по access_log, легкий способ прострелить ногу или устранение конкурентов](https://habr.com/ru/post/260647/).

Comment: Проверьте пожалуйста, правильно ли настроен .htaccess, который прикрепили к изначальному вопросу.
И как можно увеличить лимит, просто в настройках сервера мы новички, какой может быть порядок действий? Мы прописывали, но не уверенны, что это верно, в конфиге домена на ISP.

Comment: Добавил .htaccess в изначальном вопросе.

Comment: Я не использую апач (зачем если есть nginx), да и времени нет вовсе, но... обновил ответ (см. UPD к п.1).

Comment: И последний вопрос) Верно ли, что мы прописывали настройки в конфиге домена на ISP?

Comment: Вопрос не понят - о каких настройках вообще речь? Если оно про (web-) роутинг, то настройки можно прописать где угодно (зависит от провайдера и системы/панели управления, которую они используют), ну и как они будут донесены до апача (или бэкэнда) и в какой последовательности оно будет исполнено то вопрос приоритетов - обычно апач "исполняет" локальную копию .htaccess, затем из директории выше и так до веб-рута. Но то всё опять настраиваемо, см. например RewriteOptions inherit. Я без понятия как оно у вас (и вообще не использую cPanel и иже с ним - только голый *nix, только хардкор).